# Managed Debugging Assistant 'LoaderLock' has detected a problem in.exe'. How to remove this in vb.net?

Tags: windows-10, vb.net-2010, loaderlock

Managed Debugging Assistant 'LoaderLock' has detected a problem in '..bin\Debug\Paperchase.Apps.ChapterLevelZone.vshost.exe'.

Additional information: DLL '..bin\Debug\PegasusImaging.WinForms.ImagXpress7.dll' is attempting managed execution inside OS Loader lock. Do not attempt to run managed code inside a DllMain or image initialization function since doing so can cause the application to hang.

**IF I TRY TO UNCHECK THE LOADER LOCK FROM EXCEPTION SETTINGS, The application stops working when the dll is hit**How to avoid it?

Comment: Fix the problem instead of trying to disable the warning. You didn't post any code, so it's hard to offer more help. What is that DLL? Do you need a newer version perhaps? Pegasus Imaging is the old name of Accusoft and ImageXPress is at [13.1 now](https://www.accusoft.com/products/sdks/imagxpress/). What used to be acceptable 10 years ago is no longer acceptable in Windows 10.

Comment: BTW VB.NET 2010 is way too old, and definitely unsupported. Why use it at all? Why not use a current version like VS 2017 or VS 2019? The Community versions are free and largely have the same features as VS Professional. Compared to VS 2010 Pro, they're *more* powerful in most cases